# How can I, using Knockout on Sharepoint, have a div visable when a value from a list is clicked on a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, knockout.js

```
Application: 
<select data-bind="value: $data.selectedApp, options: $parent.applications, optionsText: 'ApplicationName', optionsCaption: 'Choose an Application'" style="width: 32px" name="Application list" id="dataBox">
</select>
```

With this I'm trying to make

```
<Div = "main">...</div>
```

visable when a dropdown called "USB Access Request" is clicked.
My javascript:

```
<script>
    var viewModel = {
        selectedChoice: ko.observable("USB Read/Write") ,
        selectionChanged: function(event) {
            show( "main" );  
        } 
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this

**View model:**

```
   var viewModel = function () {
       var self = this;
       self.selectedApp = ko.observable();
       self.applications = ko.observableArray([{
           "ApplicationName": "application1"},{
               "ApplicationName": "application2"},{
                   "ApplicationName": "application3"}
       ]);
   };
   ko.applyBindings(new viewModel())
```

**View :**

```
Application:
<select data-bind="value:selectedApp,options:applications,optionsText:'ApplicationName',optionsCaption:'Choose an Application'" style="width: 160px"></select>

<div data-bind="if:selectedApp">
     <h2>i'm Main DIV</h2>
</div>
```

Well i see the html is simple so its always better to use `if` binding in this case .

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/74dh736s/10/)**

Any issues let us know